# My app is not able to save new registered users to my firestore database (Flutter/Dart)

Tags: flutter, firebase, dart, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-storage

So basically I'm trying to save information (e.g. username, email etc.) about newly registered users in the firestore database. The registration is always successful and I can see the new user in the authentication tab. The database plus the storage tab, where I want to save the profile pictures, are empty.

This is the code for the register function:

```
class authmethods {

  final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance;
  final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

  //SignUp User

  Future <String> signUp({
    required String email,
    required String password,
    required String confirmPassword,
    required String username,
    required Uint8List file,
  }) async {

    String res = "Some error occured";

    try {
      if (email.isNotEmpty || password.isNotEmpty || confirmPassword.isNotEmpty || username.isNotEmpty || file != null) {
        if (password == confirmPassword) {
        
        //registering user
        UserCredential cred = await auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(email: email, password: password);

        print (cred.user!.uid);

       String photoUrl = await storagemethods().uploadImageStorage('ProfilePics', file, false);

       model.User user = model.User (
        email: email,
        uid: cred.user!.uid,
        username: username,
        photoUrl: photoUrl,
        eventsCreated: [],
        eventsAttended: [],
        );

        //add User to database
        await firestore.collection('Users').doc(cred.user!.uid).set(user.toJson());

        res = "success";
        
        } else {
          res = "Passwords have to match!";
        }
      }
    } on FirebaseAuthException catch (err) {
      if (err.code == 'invalid-email') {
        res = 'Invalid email adress';
      } else if (err.code == 'weak-password') {
        res = 'The password has to be at least 6 characters';
      }
    }
    
    catch (err) {
      res = err.toString();
    }
    return res;
  }
```

The function "signup" is then called after clicking on the "sign in" button inside the app. As I said the "createUserWithEmailAndPassword" method is successful, I am able to see the new users.

Anyone encountered a similar problem?

Thank you in advance.

Comment: I do not know why this is formatted that way. The lines: "class authmethods {

final FirebaseAuth auth = FirebaseAuth.instance; final FirebaseFirestore firestore = FirebaseFirestore.instance;

//SignUp User

Future signUp({ required String email, required String password, required String confirmPassword, required String username, required Uint8List file, }) async {"

are also part of the code.

Comment: You can format code by encircleling your code using  ```

Comment: Thank you @SrilalSachintha. Do you have any ideas on the problem itself?